C how to display the first letter in an array of strings
I would like to display the first letter of each array index.
for example:

myChar[0] should have the output of 'y' and myChar[1] 'n'

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void try(){

    char myChar[3][20];
    strcpy(myChar[0], "yee");
    strcpy(myChar[1], "no");

    printf("%s\t%s", myChar[0], myChar[1]);
}
int main(){
    try();
    return 0;
}

is there an easy way to do it?

In order to print a single character, you should be using the %c format specifier instead of %s. See the documentation for printf for further information.
Also, the first character of myChar[0] is myChar[0][0], and the first character of myChar[1] is myChar[1][0].
If you fix these things, then your code should look like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char myChar[2][20];
    strcpy( myChar[0], "yee" );
    strcpy( myChar[1], "no" );

    printf( "%c %c\n", myChar[0][0], myChar[1][0] );
}

This will print the following:
y n


Yes.
printf("%.1s\t%.1s\n", myChar[0], myChar[1]);

The .1s limits the used length of the reference string that is output.
I've added '\n' to the string to cause the output buffer to be flushed.

Two considerations arise from the comments below:

The OP has clarified their objective, wanting to print the 'n-th' character of both strings, and
@AndreasWenzel has pointed out (something that I was oblivious to) how this approach improves handling of NUL characters.

With a particular definition of the two string buffers (a 2D array of char), the language guarantees that unused bytes of the array will be set to '\0':
char myChar[3][20] = { 0 };

Without this initialisation of the array, referencing bytes beyond those set by strcpy() references uninitialised data.
Presuming the source code does not exhibit UB (referencing outside the array boundaries), using pointers to strings, pointer arithmetic and the little-used sufficient length facilities of printf()
(eg: "%.1s") obviate the need for additional code to prevent NUL being processed by printf( "%c....
printf( "%.1s\t%.1s\n", myChar[0] + 2, myChar[1] + 2 ); // 3rd char of both strings

Alternatively:
printf( "%.1s\t%.1s\n", &myChar[0][2], &myChar[1][2] ); // 3rd char of both strings


you are somewhat right, but i was looking for 1 letter specifically. your code prints out every letter till the one i was searching for. but this is cool also. Thanks very much

This solution is better than mine if it is possible that a string is empty, because in that case, it won't print a null character. Therefore, I am upvoting it.

@AndreasWenzel Thank you. :-) Edge cases are usually my Achilles heel... :-)

i did compile @Fe2O3

@7Ver7dict7 The result from using this solution fulfills your stated goal of "printing first character of each of two char/string arrays." Therefore, writing "prints out every letter till the one i was searching for" makes no sense. (Do you wish to clarify? I'm good with simply letting-it-go...)

yea, i just wanted the specific index. Dont know how to describe it.
